# Can Specs2 Result.foreach be made to work like a matcher?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, collections, specs2

Using Specs2, if I do:

```
    1 must beEqualTo(2)
    1 must beEqualTo(1)
```

The test fails (as expected)

If I do:

```
    Result.foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== 2
    }
    Result.foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== i
    }
```

The test passes

For `Result.foreach` I have to use `and` to make the test fail (as expected):

```
    Result.foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== 2
    } and
    Result.foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== i
    }
```

Why is this?
Is there a way to make it work in a less surprising way? This is very error prone - it's way too easy to not notice somebody didn't type `and`

I checked the [Specs2 user guide](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.12.0/org.specs2.guide.ForLoops.html) but there's no mention of this behaviour that I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be better documented. The `Result.foreach` function is indeed supposed to be non side-effecting. If you want side-effects you can call `foreach` directly in your specification because this one is wired in with the "throwing" behaviour of a mutable specification:

```
class TestMutableSpec extends mutable.Specification {

  "foreach must fail" >> {
    foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== 2
    }
    foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== i
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
[info] TestMutableSpec
[error] x foreach must fail
[error]  There are 9 failures
[error]  1 != 2
[error]  3 != 2
[error]  4 != 2
[error]  5 != 2
[error]  6 != 2
[error]  7 != 2
[error]  8 != 2
[error]  9 != 2
[error]  10 != 2 (TestSpec.scala:19)
[info] Total for specification TestMutableSpec
[info] Finished in 121 ms
[info] 1 example, 1 failure, 0 error
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but what you've posted above that "call foreach ... because [It] is wired in with the "throwing" behaviour of a mutable specification"  contradicts the user guide link which says: "you won’t be able to use [foreach] in ... a mutable [specification]"
Or did I completely misunderstand?

Comment: That `foreach` is the method on collections, whereas the `foreach` used in the example above has a different signature. It is inherited from the `Specification` trait and takes the collection as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, I thought that `foreach` on that page was referring to both the collection method and the one from `Specification`!. I get it now

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: mix [AllExpectations](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.12.0/org.specs2.guide.GetAllExpectations.html) into your `Specification`:

```scala
class QuickStartSpec extends mutable.Specification with AllExpectations {
  "foreach must fail" >> {
    Result.foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== 2
    }
    Result.foreach(1 to 10) { i =>
      i must_== i
    }
  }
}
```

This produces:

```
sbt> testOnly QuickStartSpec
[info] QuickStartSpec
[error] x foreach must fail
[error]  1 != 2 (QuickStartSpec.scala:8)
```

Note: I'm aware of the fact that this is not the primary purpose of the `AllExpectations` trait. However, this seems a sensible solution, given that `Result.foreach` behaves in a different way than a matcher inside a mutable specification.

Also, [according to the docs](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.12.0/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#expectations), the goal of "unit specifications" is to let users have multiple expectations per example without the need to use `and`. In light of this, the behavior of `Result.foreach` indeed seems misleading. If you think this is a bug, you may consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues).